# wp-cron still running even though DISABLE_WP_CRON is true

Tags: wp-cron

I have created a cron job to run wp-cron.php for me but I am seeing in my FPM logs where it's still running. From what I understand, is that with the cron job it wouldn't be hitting FPM to create any logs.

Is there a way to trace this and figure out whats running the file?

Comment: Where did you define `DISABLE_WP_CRON`?

Comment: @s_ha_dum In wp-config.php

Comment: Try `if (DISABLE_WP_CRON) echo 'disabled';` in your theme `header.php`. Do you get output?

Comment: Yes, it echos disabled.

Comment: What does your cron job look like?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If what you are seeing are hits to [`/wp-cron.php`](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/3.8.1/src/wp-cron.php), there is nothing really that prevents a plugin or malicious bots from making a request to that file, with or without `DISABLE_WP_CRON` set to `true`, but with it set to `TRUE` the [actual cron process should be killed](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/3.8.1/src/wp-includes/cron.php#L309).