# Cron Job Keep Running in spite of being disabled

Tags: wp-cron, optimization

I have Cron job issue in two of my sites (both hosted in siteground). It almost runs for every request made to the site

I have added following code to wp-config.php file

```
define('DISABLE_WP_CRON', true);
```

Removed all the schedules from the  CronTab in CPanel.

In spite of that I see request for

```
/wp-cron.php?doing_wp_cron
```

after each and every request. it has resulted in high CPU usage

Any help is appreciated

**Edit :**
I added following in my wp-config.php

```
define('ALTERNATE_WP_CRON', false ); 
define('WP_CRON_LOCK_TIMEOUT', 3600)
```

I also removed all the plugins & Switched to twenty Sixteen theme. disabled all cache

My Log shows me the following

```
IP     : IP of the website
URL    : /wp-cron.php?doing_wp_cron=1474993579.8446118831634521484375
Status : 200
Method : Post
Size   : 0
Protocol : HTTP/1.0
Referring URL : http://mysiteurl.in/wp-cron.php?doing_wp_cron=1474992732.7725210189819335937500
WordPress/4.6.1; http://mysiteurl.in
```

The above log appears almost with every request. If there is no request no entry appears

The 452 out of 1000 entries in my log belongs to the wp-cron

Comment: This is answered already. Check the answer here: http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/137222/102371

Comment: I have deactivated all the pluggins & activated twenty sixteen theme. The Problem still not gone away

Comment: You may also want to read this: http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/85221/doing-wp-cron-in-url-even-if-alternate-cron-is-not-in-wp-config

Comment: @cjbj I looked at that question. But my proble is not exactly the same. Anyway i added define('ALTERNATE_WP_CRON', false ); and 
define('WP_CRON_LOCK_TIMEOUT', 3600);   The problem still not gone away

Comment: How frequent does it hit your cron file?

Comment: @AhmedMahdi I have edited my question